# Getting information about EKEvent in swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm having trouble getting the right Data from the Calender. I am able to access the Calender and get all events in a given time period. However I am not able to get the EKEvent Title. Is the Title Allway in the calendarItem? How can i access it if i have the EKEevent?

```
let eventStore = EventStore.sharedInstance.eventStore
        for et in eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) {
            println(et)
        }

        let cals = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent)

        //today
        let today = NSDate()
        //yesterday
        let yesterday = NSDate()
        let last = yesterday.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-3259487.66)

        let fetchCalendarEvent =   
eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(last, endDate: today, calendars: 
cals)

        let eventlist = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(fetchCalendarEvent)

        for test in eventlist{
            println(test)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. `println(eventStore.calendarItemWithIdentifier(mob.calendarItemIdentifier).title)` gives me the desired value